# Get users stock which is assigned to them + those has not assigned yet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Each employee have their own stocks and from code below i will get the `employee` and `their stock`:

```
var employeeStockLists = db.Personcode 
 .Select(t => new user.stocklist 
   {  stockName = t.Item_Discount_Groups.Select(r=>r.Code).ToList(), 
      Person = t.Name 
   }).ToList();
```

Result:

[image: EmployeeStock]

From code below i will get Customer stocks:

```
var userStockLists = db.Bufferlager
.Where(c => c.PX2ID == model.Customers.ID) 
.Select(v=>new user.userstocks {
  userId = v.PX2ID ,
  assginedStock = v.Code ,
  Isselected = v.IsChecked }).ToList();
```

Result:

[image: userstocks]

All code together in Controller :

```
public ActionResult _userBufferlager(user model)
{
var employeeStockLists = db.Personcode
 .Select(t => new user.stocklist { 
   stockName = t.Item_Discount_Groups.Select(r=>r.Code).ToList(),
   Person = t.Name }).ToList();

var userStockLists = db.Bufferlager
  .Where(c => c.PX2ID == model.Customers.ID)
  .Select(v=>new userstocks {
    userId = v.PX2ID,
    assginedStock = v.Code,
    Isselected = v.IsChecked }).ToList();

model.EmpstockLists = employeeStockLists;
model.Userstocklist = userStockLists;

return PartialView(model);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class user
    {
        public List<stocklist> EmpstockLists { get; set; }
        public List<userstocks> Userstocklist { get; set; }

        public class stocklist
        {
            public stocklist()
            {

            }

            public string Person { get; set; }
            public List<string> stockName { get; set; }

        }

        public class userstocks
        {
            public userstocks()
            {

            }
            public int userId {get; set;}
            public string assginedStock { get; set; }
            public bool Isselected { get; set; }
        }
   }
```

**Problem**:

In my View if i loop though employeeStockLists and userStockLists :

```
  <div>
   @foreach (var emp in Model.EmpstockLists){    
       <p>@emp.Name</p>
         <div>
            <ul>
        @foreach(var stock in emp.stockName){
                  <li> <input type="checkbox" value="@stock" /> @stock </li>
             }
                    @foreach (var user in Model.Userstocklist){
                        <li> 
                         <input type="checkbox" value="@user.assginedStock" @(user.IsSelected == true ? "checked" : "") /> @user.assginedStock 
                        </li>
                                               
                          }
                    </ul>
                 </div>
               }
  </div>
```

I will get following results:

as you see there are 2 with "ABD - CIP" and 2 with "ABD - DELTEK"

```
<p>ABD</p>
<input type="checkbox" value="ABD - CIP" />
<input type="checkbox" value="ABD - DELTEK" />
<input type="checkbox" value="ABD - LANGUAGEWIRE" />
<input type="checkbox" value="ABD - VOLA" />
<input type="checkbox" checked value="ABD - CIP " />
<input type="checkbox" checked  value="ABD - DELTEK" />
```

But im looking for `this result`:

```
<p>ABD</p>
<input type="checkbox" value="ABD - LANGUAGEWIRE" />
<input type="checkbox" value="ABD - VOLA" />
<input type="checkbox" checked value="ABD - CIP " />
<input type="checkbox" checked  value="ABD - DELTEK" />
```

**Question**:

How can i get users stock which is assigned to them + those has not assigned yet?!

Can anyone please help me :)